# Sum of multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, join, sum

I think what I want to do is fairly straightforward but the data I get back varies greatly.

```
select sum(cast(vi.qty - vi.unredeemed as bigint))
  from red.dbo.setup vc
  full join red.dbo.test bt
    on bt.batch_no = vc.batch_no
  join red.dbo.live vi
 where vi.date_issued between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-01' 
   and vc.denom ='1' 
   and substring(vi.issue_id,3,1) = '4'
```

What I am trying to do is join 3 tables together then sum of `qty` of the results of the join and then minus the unredeemed so as to give a redeemed total in one row.

I have tried various amendments to my sum field but the numbers back seem huge so I think it is multiplying them.

I haven't used joins for a while and I am a bit rusty.

Comment: You have no join condition on `dbo.live`... this query won't work. Also, why a FULL JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given any condition on the second join (dbo.live) with whom you are joining. Another thing is you mentioned only join. Is it full or left or right joint. Varies depending on your condition

Comment: sorry I was copying it from a VMware client. there is a line underneath the second join;

Comment: which says on vc.denom =vi.denom. With regards to join I set it originally for a inner join but I didnt get all the data I wanted back.

Comment: what your data should be and what result are you getting. Is it small or big

Comment: I get one big number, in one row, I would like just one row returned with a more realistic number i.e. an int not a Big int

Comment: Having looked further, I would just want the join to bring back rows that are in common with each other before adding the QTY and unred columns. I tried using a inner join. but should I add an inner join for both the first part and the second join?

Comment: I have added the second join on statement in my code, I had to type my original question out manually due to working on Vmware.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you left out the `ON` clause for the second `JOIN`

```
select SUM(CAST(vi.QTY -vi.unredeemed as bigint))
from red.dbo.setup vc
FULL Join red.dbo.test bt on bt.batch_no = vc.batch_no
JOIN red.dbo.live vi ON ?? -- something needs to be added here, like vi.someId =vc.someOtherId

where vi.date_issued between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-01' and vc.denom ='1' and      SUBSTRING(vi.ISSUE_ID,3,1) ='4'
```

You are right, the "multiplication" effect you observed is due to the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) resulting from the missing ON clause. A simple JOIN with an unspecified ON clause results in a [CROSS JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join).